# Are Google App Engine Backend Instances Suitable for my App?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cpu, paas

I have a web app that will definitely be a low-traffic app (less than a few dozen hits per day), but when it does get a "hit" (the user actually has to kick off an action), it wakes up and does some heavy-duty number crunching (very CPU-intensiive) for several hours per request. As such, once live, I could foresee the server's CPUs going full bore throughout the day, even though the site itself might only receive ~15 visitors and even less number-crunching requests.

I'm trying to determine if a Google App Engine Backend Instance is appropriate for what I need.

Is there a certain "max CPU cycles" or "max CPU utilization" that a GAE Backend is capped at? If so, what is it and what are the terms & conditions surrounding it? I tried looking for it on their prices page but didn't find much relating to CPUs.

Also, if anybody knows of a Java PaaS that would be more suited for my CPU-intensive, low-traffic app (and that is free!) please speak up and let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure now, but I think that you get, what you pay for... on GAE you can run really simple apps for a few penny/month, as well as humungous apps with huge traffic...

Comment: Thanks @Dworza but I'm extremely familiar with GAE and how it works. I've just never considered how they bill you, or how they deal with free/unpaid apps, with respect to how much the CPUs are churning.

Comment: Well..I think that you'd better ask on their support than here ;) I'm just a programmer and I don't care so much about these stuff, but I've got a feeling, that you prepay for used mem/CPU performance & traffic / month...

Comment: StackOverflow is the recommended support site for GWT and GAE apps. As for what you prepay for, it depends on a lot of things, but there is a free, unpaid "tier" or service that doesn't cost *anything*. However, of course, there are resource limits for free/unpaid apps. This is the very thing that I am asking for here: **what is the max CPU utilization that I can achieve as a free app, without getting billed?**

Comment: ah so..Now I understand you..w8 for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeking for a free backend hosting, then `GAE` is probably not what you're looking for. Their free account is really limited and is good only for debugging & testing your app (and even this can be quite a problem, when you're debugging hard..)
I've done a screenshot of one of my free account admin dashboard, so you can see what are the limits for the free account. With free account you get `128MB memory` & `600Mhz CPU`

[image]